# Moment.js - How to convert date string into date?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Following up from my previous post: [Javascript Safari: new Date() with strings returns invalid date when typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154441/javascript-safari-new-date-with-strings-returns-invalid-date-when-typed)

I am using **Moment.js** to convert a date string into a date field based on user input in the text box.

This is to prevent the problem I described in the linked post for Safari and Firefox not able to render the date when Chrome is fine.

Here is the code snipper:

```js
var tempDate = moment(userInputFieldDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
alert(tempDate);
```

In Chrome, it does work fine (it use to work with the Javascript Date object too) but gives me the moment.js deprecation warning

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
>   Arguments: [object Object]
>   Error

On Firefox and Safari is just gives an `UNDEFINED DATE` in the alert window. So not entirely sure what should I be doing to convert the date string to a Date object.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you are getting a JS based date `String` then first use the `new Date(String)` constructor and then pass the `Date` object to the `moment` method. Like:

```
var dateString = 'Thu Jul 15 2016 19:31:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)';
var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
var momentObj = moment(dateObj);
var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2016-07-15
```

In case `dateString` is `15-07-2016`, then you should use the [`moment(date:String, format:String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) method

```
var dateString = '07-15-2016';
var momentObj = moment(dateString, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2016-07-15
```

Comment: What is the dateString from user input is just "07-07-2016" ?

Comment: Now I have another issue. I used the above method to take user input date. But the same user input field has a calendar drop down associated with it. If I pick a date from calendar drop down, it shows Invalid Date now :(
So works for keyboard input date but not for Calendar picked date.

Comment: You should check the format of the date, first if it's a Date object, or a string, then if a string then which format, and then use the correct `moment` object builder call with the correct `format` String (you may give also multiple possible formats as an array (check the documentation)

Comment: So I realized that in my html, the date field format is "MM-DD-YYYY" but the format I receive from the backend AJAX call is "YYYY-MM-DD". So technically the UI displays the format in MM-DD-YYYY but even if the backend is YYYY-MM-DD. but when you type it in MM-DD-YYYY, it errors out for obvious reasons. So depending on the format, I need to convert and re-convert. Am I clear or still confusing you here ?

Answer (score 7):

Sweet and Simple!
`moment('2020-12-04T09:52:03.915Z').format('lll');`


 **Dec 4, 2020 4:58 PM**

[OtherFormats](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment.locale();         // en
moment().format('LT');   // 4:59 PM
moment().format('LTS');  // 4:59:47 PM
moment().format('L');    // 12/08/2020
moment().format('l');    // 12/8/2020
moment().format('LL');   // December 8, 2020
moment().format('ll');   // Dec 8, 2020
moment().format('LLL');  // December 8, 2020 4:59 PM
moment().format('lll');  // Dec 8, 2020 4:59 PM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Tuesday, December 8, 2020 4:59 PM
moment().format('llll'); // Tue, Dec 8, 2020 4:59 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a string of date, then you should try this.

```
const FORMAT = "YYYY ddd MMM DD HH:mm";

const theDate = moment("2019 Tue Apr 09 13:30", FORMAT);
// Tue Apr 09 2019 13:30:00 GMT+0300

const theDate1 = moment("2019 Tue Apr 09 13:30", FORMAT).format('LL')
// April 9, 2019
```

or try this :

```
const theDate1 = moment("2019 Tue Apr 09 13:30").format(FORMAT);
```